# Помогите решить задачку, пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию, которая принимает на вход один аргумент `num`. Функция возвращает значение типа boolean, true, если число больше 50, и false в противном случае.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(num) {
    return num > 50;
}

console.log(check(51));
```